# VBScript text Formatting issues

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have data that has `<br>` and `<BR>` Tags in it.  I have to update a old site that is running VBScript Classic ASP.  I know little to nothing about either of these two but i came up with some hackish logic to try and quickly resolve the problem and i do not understand why it is not working.

```
    If InStr(1,objRecN("News"),"<BR>")> 1 Then
     response.write "This is 1<BR>"
     body = Replace(objRecN("News"),"<BR>", vbCrLf)
Else
     response.write "This is 2<br>"
     body = Replace(objRecN("News"),"<br>", vbCrLf)
End If
```

The Response.Writes are working effectively in proving that the right logic is being applied but the replace is not working.

```
 body = Replace(Replace(objRecN("News"),"<br>", vbCrLf), "<BR>", vbCrLf)
```

Also this is not working. This was my first attempt at trying to resolve this.  Any clues?

As soon as other logic is applied it breaks!

```
  If InStr(1,objRecN("News"),"<BR>")> 1 Then
    response.write "This is 1<BR>"
     body = Replace(objRecN("News"),"<BR>", vbCrLf )
    End If
```

Comment: What you have is correct and the replace does what you think.  What makes you think its not working? - `vbCrLf` may not be visible in rendered html ... test with "XXX"

Comment: Also FYI case insensitive version: `Replace(test, "<br>", vbCrLf, 1, -1, 1)`

Comment: @AlexK.  When i do that line `Replace(objRecN("News"), "<br>", vbCrLf, 1, -1, 1)` No formatting is applied. If i run `body = Replace(objRecN("News"),"<BR>", vbCrLf)` or `body = Replace(objRecN("News"),"<br>", vbCrLf)` They work fine when they are used seperately

Comment: @AlexK. I see it working when i replace the `vbCrLf` with another value. Why does it only apply the formatting when called once?

Comment: I cant repro, in a .vbs `msgbox Replace(Replace("A <br> B <BR>","<br>", "X"), "<BR>", "X")` I see `A X B X`

Comment: @AlexK. I can make that happen too.  The conflict is with the `vbCrLf` . You stated this may not be visible in the rendered html? Why is that? Why is it visible when the replace only targets a certain case and not both?

Comment: I mean you would not see a new line in markup: `"<em>xxx</em>" & vbcrfl & "<em>zzz</em"` would show in a browser as a single line as newlines have no meaning in HTML (thats what <br> is for)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81299/discussion-between-jackncoke-and-alex-k).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help.

```
body = Replace(body,"<BR>", "<br>")
```

Although i learned a lot from your posts. This is the code that actually fixed my problem.  I am sorry if i didn't not convey it better.

Answer (score 2):

All hard info (c) @Alex.

VBScript's [Replace function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/238kz954%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) works; it can even be asked to ignore case (mark the use of pre-defined vbTextCompare instead of magic number). If it does not seem so, the programmer is to blame. Evidence:

```
>> s = "abc<br>def<BR>ghi"
>> WScript.Echo qq(s)
>> s = Replace(s, "<br>", "!!!!", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
>> WScript.Echo qq(s)
>>
"abc<br>def<BR>ghi"
"abc!!!!def!!!!ghi"
```

If you replace with vbCrLf (or other whitespace) and then write the result to HTML, you won't 'see' the hard work Replace did for you.

If you insist on two (or more) replacements, you have to feed the previous result to the current operation. That's why your

```
body = Replace(objRecN("News"),"<BR>", vbCrLf)
body = Replace(objRecN("News"),"<br>", vbCrLf)
```

'work' separately but not together. In contrast, both

```
body = objRecN("News")
body = Replace(body,"<BR>", vbCrLf)
body = Replace(body,"<br>", vbCrLf)
```

or

```
body = Replace(Replace(objRecN("News"),"<br>", vbCrLf), "<BR>", vbCrLf)
```

will deal with all `<BR>` and `<br>`, but not with `<Br>`, which is no problem for the vbTextCompare version.

If you next data contain `<br/>`, `<br />`, and `<br  />`, you'll need a regular expression.